# Can I change a World Space canvas width to match screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity2D orthographic projection game laid out on a World Space canvas. When I change aspect ratios, the UI elements get clipped off by the screen edges. I understand I could Screen Space to solve that, but that causes other issues. I need this canvas to be in World Space.

The attached image shows the layout in 18:9 in the Scene window. I changed the aspect to 4:3 in the Game window, then went back to the Scene window. You can see how the canvas will be clipped to 4:3. If I resize the canvas width to match the screen aspect everything is fine, but I need to do that in script to match the device aspect ratio, not just through the Inspector.

It looks like I can resize the canvas to match the 4:3 screen and all is well, but how do I do that in code?

[image]

Comment: Try using a different render mode for the canvas. **Screen space - Camera** is probably fine for your uses.

Comment: Use anchors to align elements to the corners and sides of the canvas. That way they will always be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Awake`, set the width of the canvas based on the aspect ratio of the camera:

```
void Awake()
{
    RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    float canvasHeight = rt.rect.height;
    float desiredCanvasWidth = canvasHeight * Camera.main.aspect;
    rt.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, desiredCanvasWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed! I think Unity might be so vast and complex that it's hard to find answers to some questions. Or more to the point, there are so many possible solutions (or interpretations of the question) that finding an actual, simple answer that works is a real find! (I've been after this one for a good week.)

Comment: Glad I could help! Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)

Comment: Done. Thanks again. Why does my question have a -1 rating?

Comment: @RT2010 No idea. I didn't vote either way on it because it didn't show any previously made attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The Canvas Scaler component is responsible for adjusting your UI to the correct Aspect Ratio. Since you are using World Space, the canvas scaler does not apply aspect ratio adjustments.

You could change your canvas' dimensions to your screen's resolution on Awake(). If your anchors are set properly, this could do the trick.

Comment: I need to be able to zoom in, so I don't think the Screen Space modes will work for me. Could you post a code snippet on setting the anchors to the screen width? I tried using the uGUI scripts, but that too applies only to Screen Space modes. I've tried setting the camera orthogonal settings: same thing. I've googled for two days but can't find a way to set the anchors to the screen corners in World Space, so I thought I could adjust the canvas width, but haven't figured that out, either.